# Generating Function for $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: summation, generating-functions

I've been stumped by one of the exercises in the book "Number Theory" by George E. Andrews and I can't seem to figure it out. The exercise asks for the generating function for the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, starting at $a_1$, which is defined as
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$
which it tells me will turn out to condense down to
$$f(x)=-\ln(1-x)$$
I have no idea how to go from the top equation to the bottom. I already tried multiplying both sides of the top by $1-x$ in the hopes of getting a telescoping sum, but it just gets more complicated. Help?

Comment: The idea is to show the right side of both equations are equal. You wanted to go from the first to the second. Why not go from the second to the first?

Answer (score 5):

One takes the geometric series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}$$
for $|x|<1$. One then integrates termwise.

Comment: Okay, I see it now. I didn't even think to try and differentiate in order to turn it into that form.